# Truncate a String upto n characters ignoring whiteSpace

Tags: java, string, java-8

I need to truncate a String upto n characters ignoring whiteSpace.

Suppose My String is:

```
String a = "Hello World!"
```

And if n=7, then the output should be:

```
Hello Wo
```

I can do that by splitting on whitespace and then combining it back. but any better solution using Java 8?

other Solution I tried:

```
String a = "Hello World!!";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]{5}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But it didn't work. Thanks!!

Comment: Of course, `group(1)` doesn’t work when your pattern has no groups at all. You can use `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\s*+\\S){5}").matcher(a); if(matcher.find()) System.out.println(matcher.group());` or in one simple expression, `a.replaceFirst("((\\s*+\\S){5}).*", "$1")`.

Answer (score 1):

```java
        String a = "Hello World!";
        int n = 7;
        n = n + a.substring(0, n).split(" ").length - 1;
        a = a.substring(0, n);
        System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: It would not work with `a = "H e l l o World!"

Answer (score 1):

**For java 9+:**

```
String test(int cnt, String string) {
            AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(cnt);
            return string
                    .chars()
                    .boxed()
                    .peek(value -> {
                        if (!Character.isWhitespace(value)) {
                            n.decrementAndGet();
                        }
                    })
                    .takeWhile(value -> n.get() >= 0)
                    .map(Character::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
    
        }
```

**EDIT: **For java 8:****

```
 String test(int cnt, String string) {
    AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(cnt);
    return string
            .chars()
            .boxed()
            .peek(value -> {
                if (!Character.isWhitespace(value)) {
                    n.decrementAndGet();
                }
            })
            .filter(value -> n.get() >= 0)
            .map(ch->String.valueOf((char) ch.intValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());

}
```

but this will go through every character of the string regardless of the provided index. It seems there is no effective way to dynamically limit the output of the stream in java 8.

Comment: This might work but takeWhile() was introduced in Java 9. Actually I need to implement it using Java 8.

Comment: @Abhishek please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of:

```
// Pseudo-code
string // i.e: "Hello World"
n // i.e = 7
counter1, counter2
for character in string {
    if counter1 == n {
        break;
    }
    if character is not `space` {
        ++counter1;
    } else {
        ++counter2;
    }
}
return string.subString(0, counter1+counter2);
```

Comment: It's a shame you didn't write this in Java, its the only answer that works for n=0-10 on the suggested input strings so far.

Answer (score 0):

One other pragmatic solution which is more flexible for edge cases
-> what if the last index is also a whitespace e.g.

```
String ori = "Hello   World";
    int cCount = 6;
    
    String endSub = ori.substring(cCount);
    Stream<Character> endSubStream = endSub.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c);
    int whitespacesEnd = (int)endSubStream.filter(p -> Character.isWhitespace(p.charValue())).count();
    
    String beginSub = ori.substring(0, cCount);
    Stream<Character> beginSubStream = beginSub.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c);
    int whitespaces = (int)beginSubStream.filter(p -> Character.isWhitespace(p.charValue())).count();
    
    String text = ori.substring(0, cCount + whitespaces + whitespacesEnd);
  System.out.println(text);
```

https://www.online-java.com/D4qarKf5Cl

Comment: Since a Stream can be used exactly one time, there is no point in splitting a stream chain into two parts, just to have an unnecessary variable like `endSubStream`. It’s also unnecessary to box the `int` values into `Character` objects, just to use the method(s) which support `int` instead of `char` anyway. So you can simply use, e.g. `endSub.chars().filter(Character::isWhitespace).count()`. But you are counting the whitespace in both substrings, from zero to `cCount` and from `cCount` to the string’s end, followed by summing them, so you’ve just counted all whitespaces in the entire string.

Comment: Just try with `String ori = "Hello   World   ";`

Comment: @Abhishek Also fails with nCount 0,1,2 ...

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your requirement.

```
String stringToBeProcessed = "Hello World! to you";
int count = 0;
int limit = 7;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Character c : stringToBeProcessed.toCharArray()){
   if(!Character.isSpaceChar(c)){
       count = count + 1;
   }
   if(count > limit){
       break;
   } else {
       sb.append(c);
   }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```